# Visual Studio for Mac, Xamarin iOS Publishing Failed popup

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I am trying to publish a Xamarin iOS app from Visual Studio for Mac.  (ver. 17.0.2).   Xcode ver. 13.4.1 . I have the app set up correctly (I think) in App Store Connect.  The app is just for iPhone and iPad.

I am getting the following results.  It is a picture in VS for Mac so I cannot copy and paste the text into an xml file.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what the issue is with my Publish and how to fix it?

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images.  The first thing I would do in order to help you is to google the error message, which is difficult to do when it is posted as an image

Comment: @Jason.  I totally agree.  That is part of the problem.  The Publishing Failed popup is an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to increase the `CFBundleVersion`(build number) in your `Info.plist` like below and try to publish again.

```
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.0</string>
```

Comment: Apple Transporter (based on @DevenCC 's advise) gave me this: 
"The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value (409) n/a (ID: af569df4-046e-4c8d-ae7c-bf6d511a1d9a)"  

And based on the following link I edited the CFBundleVersionString and that error went away and I can now move on to the 3 new errors that are displayed. 

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696215

Comment: Good to hear that the progress is moving on!

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like an authentication error.

Did you try the same credentials you are using to push your app in https://appleid.apple.com/ ?

If they are still valid, you might just need to sign out and back into XCode / Visual studio for Mac with you valid apple identifier.

(Edited - Added my comment to this answer as it had additional value)

If the credentials works, try uploading the same package using Apple's Transporter application (apps.apple.com/ca/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12). It accomplishes the same thing, however the error messages are clearer and more verbose. Hopefully this will help pinpoint the real issue

Comment: Yes, I can login to the apple link you posted with the credentials I used to put my app in App Store Connect (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps).  I don't see anything in the image that indicates authentication error.  What am I missing.

Comment: If the credentials works, try uploading the same package using Apples Transporter application (https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12). It accomplishes the same thing, however the error messages are clearer and more verbose. Hopefully this will help pinpoint the real issue.

Comment: Trying Transporter.  working on it.  I can copy the error message!  Woot woot!

Comment: Transporter gave me this:
The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value (409) n/a (ID: af569df4-046e-4c8d-ae7c-bf6d511a1d9a)

And based on the following link I edited the CFBundleVersionString and that error went away and I can now move on to the 3 new errors that are displayed. 

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696215